# How can I speed up my lftp uploads when I'm mirroring?

Tags: bash, windows, sftp, windows-subsystem-for-linux, lftp

Here's my script:

```bsh
#! /usr/bin/bash
set -xe

local_path="${1-./}"

lftp -u user,pass host << EOF

set ftp:ssl-allow yes
set ftp:ssl-protect-data yes
set ftp:ssl-protect-list yes
set ftp:ssl-force yes

mirror --reverse --continue --parallel=5 . "$1"

quit
EOF
```

Is there anything I can change/add to the script to speed up uploads? There's a lot of neat tricks I found for speeding up downloads, but I can't find anything beyond what I already have.

I can connect to the host over FTPs or SFTP. All things being equal, would one be faster than the other? I am trying to upload a very large file, not a bunch of little ones. Therefore, I don't think the parallel option can be used.

Comment: what tricks are you referring to? Many servers do indeed limit the per-connection bandwidth for downloads (because there's potentially many concurrent downloads), and on some you can game that limitation a fair bit, but I've not met an FTP server that does that, and in upload direction (on which you probably don't have very many concurrent uploaders, so throttling individuals to benefit the overall usefulness of the service just doesn't apply). What speed do you currently achieve, and how close is that to theoretical maxima?

Comment: @MarcusMüller `-P` and `--use-pget-n=N` allow you to download multiple files at once. I think I saw somewhere that lftp can use multiple threads to download pieces of the file, too, which might improve performance. `mput` can upload multiple files at once, but I don't see a `--user-mput-n=N` flag for `mirror`.

Comment: it can only really increase throughput if the other end is throttled on a per-download-connection base, not on a per-user base or globally. Otherwise you'd be downloading things parallely in the time it would've taken them to download sequentially (what *is* really interesting is hiding the latency of download "establishment" if there's many small files, so that "I need a connection to put a file at that path" takes significant time).